# Popup Login form on top of index html

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

[image]

- I have a design requirement in html and CSS, 
       In my website user can access few components without logging in ,if user tries to access any feature which needs login authentication,a small window has to be embedded on top of existing page and all remaining features has to be blurred(not accessible until user login).. asking for user login details... I was adding a sample image for reference.... Some one suggest me how to achieve this.....
        thank you.

Comment: Please restructure your your question as it is unclear what your problem is. You will also need to provide code showing what you have tried so far.

Comment: do you want to disable clicking outside of that login page?

Comment: yes i want to disable outside login page... and also i want to know how to popup that login page on top of welcome page...

Comment: Sorry for that... i was just trying to know design concept... i was new to css ,so i haven't tried any coding  @HiddenHobbes

Answer (score 2):

You can find a similar question here: [How to implement login popup in html/javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20712195/how-to-implement-login-popup-in-html-javascript)

You can use javascript to show/hide the login form

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
function login(showhide){
if(showhide == "show"){
    document.getElementById('popupbox').style.visibility="visible";
}else if(showhide == "hide"){
    document.getElementById('popupbox').style.visibility="hidden"; 
}
}
</script>
```

and the form:

```
<div id="popupbox"> 
<form name="login" action="" method="post">
<center>Username:</center>
<center><input name="username" size="14" /></center>
<center>Password:</center>
<center><input name="password" type="password" size="14" /></center>
<center><input type="submit" name="submit" value="login" /></center>
</form>
<br />
<center><a href="javascript:login('hide');">close</a></center> 
</div>
```

Once you got that popup login, then customize it/add php or whatever you need.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#myModal').modal({
    backdrop: 'static',
    keyboard: false
})
```

and if HTML:

```
<a data-controls-modal="your_div_id" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" href="#">
```