# When I sign into my router login's page, it has this custom login form but as an alert box. How & Is it possible to make that kind of sign in form?

Tags: javascript, html

[Image of the custom sign-in box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r6D3D.png)

I want to know if it's **possible** to copy the sign in form provided as an alert box, when signing into the router alert page.

I have tried html & javascript for example:

```html
<body>
  <form id="form" action="/post.html" method='GET'>
      <...></...>
      <button type="submit">Sign In</button>
  </form>
  <script>
  alert(document.getElementById("form").innerHTML)
  </script>
</body>
```

But that didn't really work out.

Comment: Just to be sure, are you sure that the box on the router page is actually an alert-type box, and not a box that *looks* like the built-in browser's alert box, but is actually a proper modal? Perhaps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20712195/how-to-implement-login-popup-in-html-javascript/20712347 ?

Comment: @Snow [This is what it looks like](https://cdn.glitch.com/dc8815cb-78c8-4718-96d8-d7f5b13eb5a8%2Fa.png?1556151808284). I circled in red where It was overlapping the actual address bar a bit.

Comment: Yep, looks like a browser box indeed, not a modal, see the linked question

Comment: Google .htaccess and .htpasswd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking at is an [HTTP authentication](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Authentication) dialog.

These dialogs cannot be triggered by Javascript code -- other than by navigating to a page which requires authentication -- and are extremely inflexible. The only customizable element in the dialog is the HTTP realm, and many browsers (including Chrome) will no longer display even this information.

Answer (score 0):

This  is possible to do with PHP: https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php

```
<?php
if (!isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'])) {
    header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="My Realm"');
    header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
    echo 'Text to send if user hits Cancel button';
    exit;
} else {
    echo "<form action='/post.html' method='GET'>";
    echo "<input type='hidden value='{$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']}'>";
    echo "<input type='hidden value='{$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']}'>";
    echo //Other Input Fields
    echo "<input type='submit'></form>";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a Prompt Box

```js
function myFunction() {
  var txt;
  var person = prompt("Please enter your name:", "Harry Potter");
  if (person == null || person == "") {
    txt = "User cancelled the prompt.";
  } else {
    txt = "Hello " + person + "! How are you today?";
  }
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = txt;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>JavaScript Prompt</h2>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

</body>
</html>
```

source: 
https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_prompt
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_popup.asp

Comment: This isn't what the OP is asking for.